# How to get keyword arguments passed in Generic views in Django

Tags: python, django

This is my URL

```
url(r'^users/(?P<pk>\d+)/testy/$', views.MyModelUpdate.as_view(model=models.User,
    form_class=forms.UserForm, myVariable='testing'), name='my_update'),
```

This is my class view

```
class MyModelUpdate(UpdateView):


 def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       How can i get myVariable here
```

Comment: I would imagine that it would be in the kwargs, so `myvariable = kwargs['myVariable']` should work. But a general solution to these kind of problems is just to do `print args, kwargs` in the view and see what's in them!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     pk=kwargs['pk']
     myVariable=self.kwargs['myVariable']
```

Comment: i dont want pk but myvariable passed

Answer (score 0):

Edit

How about:
def get(self, request, myVariable, *args, **kwargs):